# Fields in java, "not a primitive field" error

Tags: java, field

I have been working with Fields for parsing a class to a SharedPreferences. It worked while the settings class was not a Singleton. I changed to work as a Singleton and it is not working anymore.

```
G2ASettings settings = G2ASettings.getInstance();
    Field[] fields = G2ASettings.class.getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field f : fields) {
        f.setAccessible(true);
        try {
            if (preferences.contains(f.getName()) && !f.getName().equals("INSTANCE")) {
                f.set(settings, preferences.getBoolean(f.getName(), f.getBoolean(settings))); //si no lo encuentra, pone el valor por defecto determinado en la clase
            } else {
                if (blablabla) {
                    editor.putBoolean(f.getName(), true);
                    allPreferencesDisabled = true;
                } else
   (*)----->        editor.putBoolean(f.getName(), f.getBoolean(settings)); 
            }
   (*)----->  if (!allPreferencesDisabled) allPreferencesDisabled = f.getBoolean(settings);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The error reported is the following:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: not a primitive field
```

The error is repoted at lines marked as (*) in the code.

The fields of G2ASettings are all public and boolean except INSTANCE variable which is G2ASettings type variable and is private.

I will be reporting here my progress.

EXTRA: I post here only relevant data of G2ASettings class (usual Singleton class):

```
public class G2ASettings implements Serializable {

public boolean {big amount of boolean variables]

private static G2ASettings INSTANCE = null;
private synchronized static void createInstance() {
    if (INSTANCE == null) {
        INSTANCE = new G2ASettings();
    }
}

public static G2ASettings getInstance() {
    if (INSTANCE == null) createInstance();
    return INSTANCE;
}

{public getters and setters}
}
```

Comment: It would really help if you'd post a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. There's a lot of stuff here that's unlikely to be relevant, but it would be *very* useful if we could actually reproduce it for ourselves.

Comment: what editor.putBoolean does?

Comment: Which field is the one you're on when it throws this exception?  I'd bet money it's INSTANCE, which as you said isn't a Boolean so you can't call `getBoolean()` on it.  Your if statement that checks if the current field is not INSTANCE before trying to get its Boolean value needs to be earlier and cover all of your other logic, since INSTANCE is never going to have a Boolean value and shouldn't be persisted.

Comment: @Leo, the function I posted checks if the SharedPreferences has all the required fields (these are, the fields of the G2ASettings class). If there is a missing field, it adds the field and its value (with editor.putBoolean).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which field is the one you're on when it throws this exception? I'd bet money it's INSTANCE, which as you said isn't a Boolean so you can't call `getBoolean()` on it.

Your if statement that checks if the current field is not INSTANCE before trying to get its Boolean value needs to be earlier and cover all of your other logic, since INSTANCE is never going to have a Boolean value and shouldn't be persisted.

Comment: Hello Tim, as I said, I knew the problem had to do with INSTANCE variable. Seems like "if (preferences.contains(f.getName()) && !f.getName().equals("INSTANCE"))" statement does not work since it still crashes on the first (*). Nevertheless, if I cover the whole "try" part with "String field = f.getName();
                if (!field.equals("INSTANCE")) { (blablab}" it works... stupid me jeje. I feel stupid now by asking this question. Anything I can do to delete this? I do not think it is worth it to have this question in stackoverflow. Cheers